# Are row breaks in R implicit delimiters?

Tags: r

I'm learning R through a data camp tutorial. I have noticed that row breaks seem to matter when writing a program. The code below returns an error message, since R seems to interpret "return(TRUE) as some kind of argument to the print function.

```
hello<-function(){print("hi there") return(TRUE)}
```

It "does" function - however - if I add a row break:

```
hello<-function(){print("hi there") 
return(TRUE)}
```

Is this an intentional feature of R or is it some kind of oversight on the part of Datacamp?

Comment: if you want two expressions on one line you have to separate by a semicolon. `hello<-function(){print("hi there"); return(TRUE)}`